# How to distinguish between product's page and a regular page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape:
https://www.lanebryant.com/

My crawler starts from a URL and then goes further to all the links that are mentioned on that page. Now, I scraped for other site and my logic works by checking if URL contains "products" string and then downloads the product's information. In this site there is no such thing as mentioned previously. How do I distinguish between a product's page and a regular page? (All it requires is an if statement. I hope my question is clear. For the record, here is the product's page for this site:
https://www.lanebryant.com/faux-wrap-maxi-dress/prd-358414#color/0000081590

Comment: i think the "prd-" in the url can be considered condensed form of "product" followed by a dash and then a product id. although you should use css or xpath to differentiate the links.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might be helpful in this case is to go through several product pages (visually at first), and to look for similarities in their html. If you're new to this, just go to the page and then do something similar to right click + "View Page Source" (this is the way to do it on Chrome). For the page example you gave, an example of probably relevant element would be: `<input type="submit"
class="cta-btn btn btn--full mar-add-to-bag asc-bag-action grid__item"
value="Add to Bag">`, which corresponds to the "Add to Bag" button.

Then you might look into how to use BS to actually go through the html elements of the page and do your filtering based on this.

Hope that helps!